# NHibernate cache query

Tags: nhibernate, caching

Is it any possible to query the NHibernate cache to find whether my object is there or no?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First level (session) cache? [`ISession.Contains(object obj)`](http://fisheye3.atlassian.com/browse/nhibernate/trunk/nhibernate/src/NHibernate/ISession.cs?r=2659#l182).

Comment: inside of unit test, how do i get the access to ISession, should i just create a new session?

Comment: You can either create a session factory and from there a session, or just mock the ISession with moq or Rhino.Mocks. But that's another question.