# Query the NHibernate session scope cache - NonUnique Exception

Tags: nhibernate

I'm having a problem in my application when I'm saving an entity. On occasion I'd get NonUnique exception on that entity from NHibernate. Now, I know what causes those kind of exceptions and how to deal with them, but since the application codebase is rather large (200K LOC), it's very hard to pinpoint which object it was exactly that caused that error.

What I'd like to do is query or extract somehow all the objects that NHibernate keeps in the session scope cache, so i'd have a better idea of what it was exactly that caused that exception.

Is there a way to do something like that ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [NHibernate cache query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395572/nhibernate-cache-query)

Comment: That question only shows how to check if an object is already there. I want to see all the other objects in there, so I can located the conflicting object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is nothing in ISession to "list" its contents. You could use interceptors or event listeners to track and log your operations though.

Comment: Any idea on how I might try to debug something like this then ?

Comment: @Miki: as I said, use interceptors or event listeners